# Insert icon/image inside tabitem in delphi xe5 for Android

Tags: android, delphi, tabcontrol, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to add an image\icon inside tabtitem with delphi-xe5 for Android. I'm following this manual 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Tab_Components_to_Display_Pages_(iOS_and_Android)

But i can not find the way for setting the tabitem Stylelookup to tabitemcustom. The only option i have is tabitemstyle. By the way, the property CustomIcon doesn't appear as well.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can you Bitmap Style Designer (check you bin folder) to redesign your tab project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you linked clearly states:

> In your iOS apps, you can use custom icons as well as custom text for tab pages.
>
> **Note:** In **Android** apps, custom icons and custom styles are not used on tabs.

Please note the last paragraph. In Android apps, **custom icons and custom styles are not used on tabs.** The text indicates that iOS allows custom icons and styles, and Android does not use them.

It goes on to say (in that same paragraph):

> To create multi-device apps that support both iOS and Android, you need to set the StyleLookup property for your TTabItem **when iOS is the selected design-time device** in the FireMonkey Mobile Form Designer.

Answer (score 0):

As you says such behaviour is for Delphi xe5, but for Delphi XE7, as the documentation says, such behaviour is possible but i have not been able to make it works.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Tab_Components_to_Display_Pages_(iOS_and_Android)

Has anybody make it works?